# How to used np.where to return a list of tuples with all positions in a 2D numpy array equal to zero?

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I am learning about numpy and as an exercise I have to create a function possibilities that has as an input a numpy 2D array with integers and must return a list of tuples where the values are zeros. I've been told that numpy has a function where that can help. I read the docs but couldn't understand it at least not for this task so I had to do it with for loops like this:

```
def possibilities(board):
    not_occupied = []
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[0])):
            if board[i][j] == 0:
                not_occupied.append((i,j))
    return not_occupied
```

Board is somthing like this:

```
board = [[1,2,0],[0,0,1],[2,0,1]]
```

How I could use numpy where to do that instead?

Comment: A list of tuples like this is ok if you want to iterate through the points, but the tuple of arrays that `where` gives is better for accessing all points at once.  `argwhere` is the transpose of `where`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [argwhere](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html):

```
import numpy as np

board = [[1, 2, 0],
         [0, 0, 1],
         [2, 0, 1]]

result = np.argwhere(np.array(board) == 0).tolist()
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 1]]
```

If the coordinates must be tuples you could do:

```
result = [tuple(coord) for coord in np.argwhere(np.array(board) == 0).tolist()]
```

**Output**

```
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the zip function to re-pair the result of where
list(zip(*np.where(board == 0)))

Comment: thanks I didn't knew this function, very useful indeed.